# Updating page number from service

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to add the page number. for that I have a service so, from there accordingly i can update the page number.

But I am not able to achieve this. any one help me to get it done for me?

when i click first page, i am getting updated the page number. but this is not working with next page ( page-second).

service:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  startPage:0,
  pageIndex:Ember.computed(function(){ //calls only one time
    return this.get('startPage') + 1;
  }),
  totalPages:2
});
```

Route:

```
model(){ //calling controller
    this.controllerFor(this.routeName).send('pageHandler');
  }
```

[here is my live demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/80618603ab46530a8e48a9419ec32033?openFiles=services.page-service.js%2C)

Comment: You don't have the code for `pageHandler` shown...  that might help.

Comment: Your computed property has no dependent key, it will be computed once and the value will be cached for the lifetime of your app. Does start page ever change?

Comment: For additional information on how computed properties behave check out [this section of the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_computed-properties-in-action)

Comment: Any one show me a correct approach?

Comment: Also, you don't actually set a current page. In your pageIndex property you increase the startPage property, but there is nothing saved. Try `this.set('startPage', this.get('startPage') + 1)`